# Create Subgroups in customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, php-5.4, customer-group

Magento provides a functionality of customer groups,which are used through out our website.But is it possible to create sub groups to the parent groups and use them in efficiently through out our magento website?
I just have a basic knowledge of magento,I am confused that is it possible? If yes then how?
Can anyone help me!

Comment: You cannot create sub groups in magento by default, what is that exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In the community edition there is no way to create subgroups. A customer can belong to a single group.
But in EE you have a feature called customer segmentation.
A segment can be created based on rules.
You cannot create sub segments, but you can define an other segment with additional rules to simulate sub segments.